# How to OCR and/or recreate lines of Egyptian Hieroglyphs in Unicode/HTML?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, unicode, image-processing, fonts

I am wondering how to take [these Hieroglyphs](http://www.etana.org/sites/default/files/coretexts/14900.pdf) and make them into [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_Hieroglyphs_(Unicode_block)). I read through [the Tesseract docs](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/TrainingTesseract-4.00#creating-training-data) on how to create training data, but it seems largely tailored toward "traditional" writing, that goes in one direction and has only one character per vertical-space-per-line. Whereas in Egyptian hieroglyphs, it is sort of nested writing, you might have 3 characters stacked vertically, followed by 2 characters stacked vertically, etc.

So I'm wondering what the best option is for doing the *full spectrum*, of taking one of the hieroglyphic images in that book, like this:

[image]

And layout not completely horizontally like this:

but instead layout in HTML exactly like they are laid out in the original textbook.

What I would imagine to do is, use OCR (or similar technology?) to identify the individual glyphs. I would manually draw squares around characters and map them to unicode characters. Then I would go and use that as training data somehow. Then it would go, page-by-page, through the document, and *layout* the text *as it sees it* in the document (with Egyptian Hieroglyphic quirks and all, everything in the proper place). I would imagine that there would be some tool that could use my manually trained squares and return `{ x: ..., y: ..., w: ..., h: ..., char: ... }` for each glyph it finds. Then I can simply do my think with that data and convert it to HTML with CSS and absolute positioning.

The question is, how do I do that middle step? How do I do everything up to the HTML portion even? Should I be looking at Tesseract, or is there a more general tool like an "image recognition" tool that I could use to take my models (of some kind, x/y/w/h perhaps of boxes) and return my x/y/w/h/char array for each page. How can I do that, at a high level? I can figure out the specific CLI commands to run, or library API methods to call, I am just not sure what the state of the art is here and what *type* of tool would be best and easiest in this case.

Comment: I am on a similar mission, did you reach any progress, maybe we colab ?

Comment: @Omar Nope, made no progress here, if you figure anything out definitely update!

Comment: I'm moving far away from this approach, it is way too complex, I'm going into 1. OCR detect glyph
2. extract into PNG
3. make a characterset, similar to the UnicodeBlock font, but with advanced vocabulary

difficult mission, I made a prototype, skeleton app that simplifies experiementation. I can share, to experiment with different algos, I also found a research paper on the topic

Comment: My goal is to make a new Unicode Font with extensive vocabulary from Middle Egyptian

Comment: @Omar wow really cool, I'd love to see it when it becomes available!